# 50% Sections Won't Stack On Mobile

Tags: html, css, layout, height, responsive

**EDIT**
I corrected a typo and updated the JSFiddle and this post to reflect the change. The Headline should be taking up 100% height and it isn't. Still looking for thoughts.

This is looking just as I want it on desktop. I can't figure out why on mobile it won't take up 100% of the height and stack on top of each other. The Headline also loses the color background. [Here's the JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/dn12Loez/2/)

**HTML**

```
    <div class="about-header">
      <h2>Headline</h2>
    </div>

    <div class="about-section">

      <div class="about-text">
        <p>The first chunk of text to let users know they gotta read a 
         little bit. If they want. It's not mandatory or anything.</p>

        <p>The second group of text, a nice chunk of descriptive text that 
        explains some more about this website. It really hopes you can help 
        me troubleshoot this problem that I am facing.</p>

        <p>Another grouping of text goes right in this little section here 
        that should go on for a while.</p>
     </div><!-- END ABOUT TEXT -->

    </div> <!-- END ABOUT SECTION-->
 </section>
</div><!-- END CONTAINER -->
```

**CSS**

```
*{
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
}

html{
  font-size:62.5%;
}

html,
body{
  height:100%;
  background-color:#FFF;
  color:#000;
  font-family:"Arial", "Helvetica", sans-serif;
  font-size:12px;
  font-size:1.2rem;
}

.container{
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
 }

.container *{
  box-sizing:border-box;
}

.row{
  min-width:85%;
  margin:0 auto;
}

.row:before,
.row:after{
  content:"";
  display:table;
  clear:both;
}

#about{
  height:100%;
}

.about-header{
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
  background-color:lightblue;
  position:relative;
}

.about-header h2{
  display:table-cell;
  vertical-align:middle;
  text-align:center;
  text-transform:uppercase;
}

.about-section p{
  font-size:1rem;
  padding-left:1.2rem;
  padding-right:3rem;
  padding-bottom:1.5rem;
}

.about-text{
  display:table-cell;
  vertical-align:middle;
}

.about-section{
 width:100%;
 height:100%;
 position:relative;
```

}

```
/**** MEDIA QUERY****/
@media all and (min-width:500px){

.about-section{
  width:50%;
  height:100%;
  background-color:#FFF;
  left:50%;
  display:table;
  position:absolute;
}

.about-header{
  width:50%;
  height:100%;
  background-color:lightblue;
  right:50%;
  display:table;
  position:absolute;
}

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have a typo.

```
.about-head{
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    background-color:lightblue;
    position:relative;
}
```

Should be:

```
.about-header {
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    background-color:lightblue;
    position:relative;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for pointing out this oversight. I made the change. This solved the color and format. The div isn't taking up 100% of the height like it does on desktop though.

Comment: Ah, your row does not have a height in mobile.  Try setting that to 100%.

Comment: I should have added if you want the h2 to be centered the display cannot be set to table-cell.

Comment: Table cell is how I get it to be centered in the light blue div on desktop. I want it to do the same on mobile, just stacked on the white text div which is also 100% height.

Comment: If you want the h2 tag to be centered in desktop just add the dispaly: table-cell in the media query.  If you want them both to be vertically aligned and centered in mobile and desktop make sure .about-header has display: table.  If you don't care about internet explorer you can look into using flex to stack and align divs.

Comment: I forgot to add for the vertically display in both keep the display: table-cell.